# Boost ld: final link failed: Bad value: relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined hidden symbol

Tags: c++, linux, boost, linker

I'm Trying to Link boost library with our code, I'm Getting the Following error

ld: /boost/lib/laxno/libboost_thread.a(thread.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined hidden symbol `_ZTCN5boost10wrapexceptINS_21thread_resource_errorEEE0_NS_16exception_detail10clone_implINS3_19error_info_injectorIS1_EEEE' can not be used when making a shared object
ld: final link failed: Bad value

I have built the boost with the GCC 7.4.0 with the following command
./b2 cxxflags="-fPIC -std=c++14" cflags="-fPIC" -j4

Getting the following error if I exclude the "-fPIC" flag while building the boost libs:

/boost/lib/laxno/libboost_thread.a(thread.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.text' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/boost/lib/laxno/libboost_thread.a: could not read symbols: Bad value

Comment: Boost version is 1.70

Comment: related postings may help, found with this [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=Bad+value%3A+relocation+R_X86_64_PC32+against+undefined+hidden+symbol)

Answer (score 1):

Using the boost libs and boost .so files from the boost install location instead of build location fixed the issue.

Comment: Can you eloborate how you did that?